# How to upgrade a python library in a supercomputer

Tags: python, linux, supercomputers, auto-sklearn

I am using Tinaroo (University of Queensland) super computer

When I call to run my code using

```
qsub 70my_01_140239.sh
```

I get this error

```
autosklearn.util.dependencies.IncorrectPackageVersionError: found 'dask' version 2021.11.2 but requires dask version >=2021.12
```

cleary i need to upgrade dask library

but I don't have access to upgrade it

Here is the actual code for  `qsub 70my_01_140239.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#PBS -A qris-jcu
#
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=24:mem=120GB
#PBS -l walltime=06:00:00
#PBS -N 70my_01_140239


shopt -s expand_aliases
source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh
cd ${PBS_O_WORKDIR}
module load python
module load anaconda
python 70myb.py 8000 3 "E&V" 2 1 15 10000 120 24
```

I tried adding `conda install dask` in **70my_01_140239.sh** but it does not work as i have no permission to upgrade the library.

does anyone know How to upgrade a  python library in a supercomputer

Comment: I've never used a supercomputer, but FWIW, I assume it'd be better to ask the people who manage it, not us. Apart from that, what access do you have exactly?

Comment: @wjandrea support do not reply, and i think most supercomuter use the same OS and structure. looking for someone with knowledge

Comment: Are you happy with the python version itself? Then just install your own python virtual environment and add the modules you want.

Comment: @tdelaney how to do that? how can install my own pythin virtual env?

Comment: Well what access do you have exactly? For example, if you don't have internet access on it or can't sideload files or w/e, then you'd need to get creative.

Comment: @wjandrea I am a student, I have access to the internet, i tried ping google.com and I got a response

Comment: There are a lot of ways to install a virtual environment. Look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html to start.  Conda is another good option https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/.

Comment: Yeah, if you have full access with `conda`, you're golden. Check out [this answer](/a/59737857/4518341) (TLDR: create an environment first and activate it, then install the package). You'll also need to activate the environment in your script.